# The Envelope (wave front) of a span of plane waves.

Tags: fourier-analysis, physics

Imagine we have for every real direction $\mathbf n \in \mathbb R^3$ a plane wave, be it either quantum, eletric, magnetic, acoustic or in my case some sheets of paper I am holding up. Each of these plane waves propagates with speed $c(\mathbf n)$ and amplitude
$$
f(\mathbf n \cdot x - c(\mathbf n) t),
$$
where $f$ is a scalar function. 
Now here comes the question: what would be the envelope of all these plane waves? Said in another way, if
$$
W(x,t) = \int_{\mathbf R^3} f(\mathbf n \cdot x - c(\mathbf n) t) d\mathbf n,
$$
then, for each $t$, what is the surface $\mathcal S$ where $W(x,t)$ will be locally larger, and by locally I mean 
$$  x \in \mathcal S \implies     W(x,t) = \max_{|s^\perp| <<1} W( s^\perp+ x,t), $$

where $s^\perp$ is in the orthogonal compliment of the plane tangent to $\mathcal S$ at the point $x$. The answer is independent of $f$, and I believe now that it involves some simple intuitive trick (if I could I would add a picture).

Physically, this is the surface where the plane waves "intersect" and create a focus. This question is important for Fourier Transforms (other transforms) and the solver will certainly gain dark intuitive powers regarding waves.

Comment: what is variable $x$?

Comment: It is the spatial position $x \in \mathbb R^3$. For every position $x$ and time $t$ the wave has a scalar amplitude, ex: $f(\mathbf n \cdot x - c(\mathbf n)t)$.

Comment: It depends on what your scalar-field, $f$, is. Contours of $f$ at time $t$ will identify the wavefronts, ofcourse. When any surface integral of any contour will be a global maxima; it depends on what your scalar field is.

Comment: Thanks, I now realise the question needed to be better mathematically defined.

Comment: This stuff is known as the angular spectrum representation of the field.  Very useful in optics.